# SMB 3 & Windows 7

Tags: smb, azure-files

I currently map a drive letter in Windows 10 to an Azure Files account using the provided http/SMB3 connection mapping and this works great.
It doesn't however work on another pc running Windows 7.

I understand that Windows 7 does not support SMB3, but is there possibly another way around this?  Is it even remotely possible to map a Windows 7 drive letter to an Azure Files account?

Answer (score 1):

Azure requires external SMB traffic to be encrypted. SMB encryption is only available on 3.xx